# Overriding log2lin and lin2log for Highcharts does not appear to work

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been trying to get negative values to display on a "logarithmic" axis - in the sense that the log function won't be mathematically accurate, but negative values will still have some sort of exponential effect where values with smaller magnitudes are more spaced out.

I've tried [this solution](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/snippets/alternative-maths-plotting-negative-values-logarithmic-axis/) ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/1z001nhy/)) which hides error messages then overrides Highcharts' native log2lin and lin2log methods such that this effect is supported for negative numbers.

```
(function (H) {
    // Pass error messages
    H.Axis.prototype.allowNegativeLog = true;

    // Override conversions
    H.Axis.prototype.log2lin = function (num) {
        var isNegative = num < 0,
            adjustedNum = Math.abs(num),
            result;
        if (adjustedNum < 10) {
            adjustedNum += (10 - adjustedNum) / 10;
        }
        result = Math.log(adjustedNum) / Math.LN10;
        return isNegative ? -result : result;
    };
    H.Axis.prototype.lin2log = function (num) {
        var isNegative = num < 0,
            absNum = Math.abs(num),
            result = Math.pow(10, absNum);
        if (result < 10) {
            result = (10 * (result - 1)) / (10 - 1);
        }
        return isNegative ? -result : result;
    };
}(Highcharts));
```

However, the only change I observed is that negative values were hidden. This behavior is observed on the demo site as well, so I suspect it's not an issue with my code.

[This is what I see on the demo site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq7yg.png)

Setting the axis extreme to a negative value would also produce the original [error message](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/10/). May I know how to fix this such that negative values can be displayed with the desired behavior on the logarithmic axis? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for sharing this post, it seems like a regression because it used to work fine in the versions < 8.0.4.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bj3dwe4t/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/8.0.4/highcharts.js"></script>
```

I reported it on Highcharts GitHub issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13914

If you don't need any of the new features please use the last working version of the code.

Comment: This works, thank you! Will monitor the Github issue thread for updates.